# Netty TCP Socket InputStream

Tags: java, sockets, spring-boot, tcp, netty

Netty TCP Server is running at port `8000` receiving `NMEA` format data. It uses  [Marine API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.marineapi/marineapi) library to convert the gibberish to a meaningful information which needs input stream from the socket.

```
SentenceReader sentenceReader = new SentenceReader(socket.getInputStream());
sentenceReader.addSentenceListener(new MultiSentenceListener());
sentenceReader.start();
```

How can i get inputstream for netty server port being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SentenceReader` does not have any method to accept "streamed in"  data, however with subclassing, it can be made to accept the data.

The core of [`SentenceReader`](https://github.com/ktuukkan/marine-api/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/marineapi/nmea/io/SentenceReader.java) uses a `DataReader` for its data, normally this datareader is polled from a seperate thread `SentenceReader` itself, and we can modify this structure to get what we need.

First, we subclass `SentenceReader` with our own class, give it the proper constructor and methods we want, and remove the effect of the start and stop methods. We provide `null` as the file for now (and hope future versions provide a method to pass a datareader in directly)

```
public class NettySentenceReader extends SentenceReader {
    public NettySentenceReader () {
        super((InputStream)null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }
}
```

We now need to implement all functionality of the internal class [`DataReader`](https://github.com/ktuukkan/marine-api/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/marineapi/nmea/io/AbstractDataReader.java) inside our own Netty handler, to replicate the same behaviour

```
public class SentenceReaderHandler extends
         SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    private SentenceFactory factory;
    private SentenceReader parent;

    public SentenceReaderHandler (SentenceReader parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        if(!ctx.channel().isActive())
            return;
        //ActivityMonitor monitor = new ActivityMonitor(parent);
        this.factory = SentenceFactory.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        //ActivityMonitor monitor = new ActivityMonitor(parent);
        this.factory = SentenceFactory.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    // This method will be renamed to `messageReceived` in Netty 5.0.0
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String data)
             throws Exception {
        if (SentenceValidator.isValid(data)) {
            monitor.refresh();
            Sentence s = factory.createParser(data);
            parent.fireSentenceEvent(s);
        } else if (!SentenceValidator.isSentence(data)) {
            parent.fireDataEvent(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        //monitor.reset();
        parent.fireReadingStopped();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        if(!ctx.channel().isActive())
            return;
        //monitor.reset();
        parent.fireReadingStopped();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable e) {
        parent.handleException("Data read failed", e);
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to integrate this into a Netty pipeline:

```
SentenceReader reader = new NettySentenceReader();
bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    private static final StringDecoder DECODER = new StringDecoder();
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(DECODER);
        pipeline.addLast(new SentenceReaderHandler(reader)); 
    }
});
```

Comment: `if(!ctx.isActive())`  the method `isActive()` does not exist

Comment: fireSentenceEvent(net.sf.marineapi.nmea.sentence.Sentence)' is not public in 'net.sf.marineapi.nmea.io.SentenceReader'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: If that method is not accessible, we need to use reflection to forcefully get access to that method, but I don't have time to explain that today, will do tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily as InputStream is blocking and netty is an async - non blocking API.